# `fbcon/cursor_blink` permissions reset at reboot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, filesystems, screen, framebuffer

### Context

I need to stop the cursor from blinking on an external screen of my raspberry-pi in order to display a home-made interface on `/dev/fb0`.

For this purpose I created a group `cursor_blink` in which I put my user and changed the permissions of the file `/sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink` as follow:

```
chown root:cursor_blink /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
chmod 664 /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

So my user in the group `cursor_blink` can write `1` or `0` to display and hide the cursor from the screen.

### Problem

I had this working, but reinstalling it on another system makes that this file is now reset to the default permissions every time I reboot, the mode becomes again `600` and the owner `root:root` after reboot instead of `660` and `root:cursor_blink`

It seems that **the file is recreated** (some digging in the last edit times with `stat` corroborate this element).

### Question

Is there a way to keep the permissions as set, and prevent them of being reset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment the solution I found is to add a `crontab` task to correct the permissions at boot:

```sh
crontab -e
```

```sh
# ...
# add this line at the end of the file :

@reboot chown root:cursor_blink /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink && \
        chmod 664 /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

*Prerequisite: The group `cursor_blink` should be created and the user should be added to it before: `usermod -a -G user cursor_blink`.*

If you have a better solution, feel free to add.